# Identity a QFN chip

Tags: power, identification, buck

I would appreciate your help in identifying an electronic chip in a QFN package with 24 pins that belongs to a Roland R-05 sound recorder.

The component is located near the DC/battery input and I think it is used for power management.

[image: The chip is IC6]

The only inscription that appears on it is EAC; the second line is the manufacture date.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any clue in a deep Google search. I am attaching a picture of the board where the chip (IC6) is located.

Comment: +1 for very clear photo including the surroundings. It looks like only a few pins are used. Does the bottom side of the PCB right under it reveal any clues what goes where from it?

Comment: It's TQFP not QFN.

Comment: @nataf10 slways specify the component label, if it is on the board

Answer (score 1):

IC7 is the [LTC3101](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3101fb.pdf) from Linear Technology (now Analog Devices).

The logo is quite recognisable as linear technologies. Coupling that with "QFN-24" and "3101" yeilds the part above.

This is a DC/DC converter for creating a regulated 3.3V output from either a battery source, or a ~5V source such as USB.

---

IC6 appears to be a TQFP (leaded) package, rather than a QFN (leadless), though 24-pins is not a common number of pins for QFP packages. In which case it is likely to be one of the older style punch-seperated QFN packages which did have that chamfered body with a stepped base that may explain why it looks leaded. I'm unable to find anything with that marking though.